# C3 scatter plot show all tcks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js, scatter

My Y axis is four categories.
My X Axis is 6 categories.

I won't always have data for each, but I need to show the tick marks all the times.
I've gone with inserting `0` counts for points that I don't want to show. But that still triggers mouseover events for hovering (which seems to be unacceptable). When I filter our the non-data all my tick marks go away.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'null' instead of '0'

Here, 'gnu' still shows up as a category

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xs: {
            setosa: 'setosa_x',
            versicolor: 'versicolor_x',
        },
        // iris data from R
        columns: [
            ["setosa_x", "ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"],
            ["versicolor_x", "eel", "fox", "gnu", "hen"],
            ["setosa", "0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2"],
            ["versicolor", 1.3, 1.3, null, 1.3],
        ],
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            label: 'Sepal.Width',
            tick: {
                fit: false
            },
            type: "category"
        },
        y: {
            label: 'Petal.Width',
            type: "category"
        }
    }
});
```